# django change formfield data

Tags: django, forms, instance

I am working with django-taggit (https://github.com/alex/django-taggit). To let a user add tags i use a formfield that I convert into the tags and add them.

However, when i try to load the template for editing. i get the taggit objects in my bar.
Now i want to convert those in a normal readable string again. 
However, i can't seem to edit that field of the instance before passing it to my form.

The Form:

```
class NewCampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
""" Create a new campaign and add the searchtags """

    queryset = Game.objects.all().order_by("name")

    game = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=queryset, required=True)
    tags = forms.CharField(required=False)
    focus = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=Campaign.CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ["game", "tags", "focus"]
        exclude = ["owner"]
```

my model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    """ campaign information """

    ROLEPLAY = "Roleplay"
    COMBAT = "Combat"
    BOTH = "Both"
    CHOICES = (
        (ROLEPLAY, "Roleplay"),
        (COMBAT, "Combat"),
        (BOTH, "Both"),
    )

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    focus = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CHOICES)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

view:

```
def campaign_view(request, campaign_id):
    campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, pk=campaign_id)
    campaign.tags = "Some string"
    new_campaign_form = NewCampaignForm(instance=campaign)
```

But when i try this i still get the taggit objects([]) in my inputfield instead of the "Some string"
How should i solve this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how i overlooked this. But this works:

```
new_campaign_form = NewCampaignForm(instance=campaign, initial={"tags": "Some String"})
```

Excuse me, should have looked more and try better